# Validar que una pestaña especifica de Google Chrome no se haya abierto desde C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

Quisiera poder validar si ya abri una url en el google chrome desde C#

El comando que estoy empleando es:

**Process.Start("chrome", $"--start-fullscreen --app={Url}?token={tk}");**

Sin embargo no encuentro la forma para preguntar si la url ya ha sido abierta en alguna pestaña de mi navegador Chrome.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Process te puede dar la salida del proceso, y entre otras cosas la misma información que el administrador de tareas. Por lo que la única forma que tendrías de saberlo es controlando si el procedimiento está activo o inactivo u optar por otra forma

Comment: ¿Cómo dijo falta más información de lo que intentas, tienes bloqueado que se abran nuevas pestañas o no puede escribir url?

Comment: Probablemente sea mejor usar selenium o algún programa de automatización. A menos que hackees el navegador no lo tendrás simple